# How can I add headers to the requests made by a DataManager using the OData adaptor?

Tags: ej2-syncfusion

The app I'm working on uses Syncfusion EJ2 Grids with data loaded by our code and passed to the Grid for rendering. I don't know why it was written this way and not with the DataManager class available, but it's how things are.

I want to move some things to using a DataManager to more easily enable pagination and advanced sorting/filtering, but since the server requires all requests to have an `Access-Token` header (no, I don't understand why we don't use cookies, but I don't have control over that), I need to be able to add that header to outgoing requests.

I've searched the documentation, particularly:

- https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/grid/data-binding/remote-data
- https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/data/adaptors#odata-adaptor

I've also checked out the provided types for both the DataManager and the ODataAdaptor, but the parameters are un-commented and none of them seem like a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I'm blind. There is a `headers` property under the `DataOptions` type, and my eyes just skipped over it.

Lesson learned: Don't rubber-ducky to StackOverflow, you'll just embarrass yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, tested using Vue3 data grid:

```
 const dm = new DataManager({
  adaptor: new UrlAdaptor(),
  url: '/api/data',
  batchUrl: '/api/batch',
  headers: [
        { HeaderName: "value" }
    ]
});
```